# Join Column through intermediate table

Tags: java, hibernate

I have following tables(with fields):

1. **user**  : (fields)  id,  name
2. **user_service_details**: (fields) user_id, super_user_id, label

where each user has a super user, and super_user is also of type user

In my new table(survey)

**survey**: (fields) user_id, super_user_id

I want to store super_user through user_id like

```
private User superUser;

    @JoinTable(name="user_service_details",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="super_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
        public User getSuperUser() {
            return superUser;
        }
```

But it is not working as it is saying that pojo for UserServiceDetails already exist and it is duplicate.

```
@Table(name = "user_service_details")
public class UserServiceDetails
```